# pointer to class A is passed to class B, but when B is deleted, A is as well. How to keep A?

Tags: c++, qt

in a C++-project in Qt-creator I have a class Settings that stores some settings which I want to use in class App (App can manipulate Settings and I need this updated data after the deletion of App).
First I defined a pointer for each class, declared it and passed Settings to App.

settings.h:

```
class Settings {
public:
  Settings();
// ...
}
```

app.h:

```
class App {
public:
  App(Settings *set);
private:
  Settings *s;
// ...
}
```

app.cpp:

```
App::App(Settings *set){
s = set;
// manipulate s...
}
```

main.h

```
Settings* s;
App* a;
```

main.cpp

```
// ...
s = new Settings;
a = new App(s);

// ...
if(!aIsNeeded)
 delete a;
// from here, s is deleted too
```

That works fine, until I need App again with the same Settings. When I call
    a = new App(s);
there is an exception because s seems to be deleted too.

Is there a better aproach for this? Why is s deleted?

Thanks for answers!

Edit: the problem was that Settings as QWidget was added to the ui of App and therefore became a child of App. I solved it with adding this line in the destructor of `a` before `delete ui;`:

```
s->setParent(0);
```

Thanks for all the hints!

Comment: This has nothing to do with qt, doesn't it?

Comment: Do you have a destructor for `App` ?

Comment: Your code does not show any deletion of `s`. Do you have a destructor in class App? Btw, you should use smart pointers rather than ordinary pointers.

Comment: Seems like perils of not following Rule of Three.

Comment: If `s` is being deleted, that's because there's something in the code you haven't shown us that deletes it. Simply deleting an object that contains a pointer to it won't delete it, unless the destructor does so explicitly. I would recommend using smart pointers, to make all ownership relations explicit.

Comment: Do you really have to use pointers here?

Comment: I think I found the problem, it's related to qt (I tried to simplify too much it seems): the class `Settings` inherits `QWidget` and is added to the `ui` of `App` (`ui->layout->addWidget(s);`). When I delete `a` the destructor deletes the ui and (now I assume) because `s` has made a child of `ui`, it will deleted as well.
or not, the debugger tells me that `s` is still there with all its variables when `delete ui;` in the destructor of `a` has finished. Only when I jump back to main.cpp some variables in `s` have as adress `<Memory access error>`.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen by default. It seems likely that `App` has a destructor that is deleting that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the member is freed in the destructor of `a`, in which case it's up to you to define the ownership of `Settings`. Since it's created outside of `App`, I'd say it's ownership doesn't belong to `App`, so `App` shouldn't delete it.

Of course, you wouldn't have this problem if you used smart pointes.